# How can I obtain 2 blocks of 3 columns on the same page with TFPDF

Tags: tcpdf

I want to create a layout of 2 blocks on a page, each with 3 columns. I am currently using [example 10](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_010.phps) of the documentation and the [`setEqualColumns()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aeb84582f37f9d68c1a9f5723849d0009) method.
How can I fix a maximum height?

The result I want to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must use `SetAutoPageBreak()` and `resetColumns()` functions ([more details here](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html)). Be careful, if your text is longer than the allowed space, the rest of the text will be written on the next page.

For example :

```
//Set the distance from the bottom the first block must stop : 130
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 130);

//Write the first block : 3 columns, width 50
$pdf->setEqualColumns(3, 50);
$pdf->writeHTML($content_1);

//reset columns
$pdf->resetColumns();

//reset the X position and the page break
$margins = $pdf->getMargins();
$pdf->setX($margins['left']);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $margins['bottom']);

//write the chapter title (like in the TCPDF example 10) 
$pdf->SetFillColor(200, 220, 255);
$pdf->Cell(180, 6, 'Chapter 2', 0, 1, '', 1);

//write the second block
$pdf->setEqualColumns(3, 50);
$pdf->writeHTML($content_2);
```